# High Performance Method to Reset CSS Animations

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, animation

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fkvqk0on/1/

I'm writing a Cordova app with a button that "pops" every time you tap it. I also want it to pop after a swipe, so I wrote a system to call the animation from JavaScript. Here how it works currently:

- There is a CSS animation for the pop
- On a swipe, the JS adds a class to the button that gives it that animation
- Next time there's a swipe, the JS removes the class and then adds it again

This system runs well on my computer, but it's laggy and slow on my phone. Sometimes it fails to animate if I swipe several times in a row! How can I make a more optimized system to do this?

```js
var target = document.getElementById("textTarget");
var button = document.getElementById("button");

function pop() {
  target.classList.remove("popAnimation");
  setTimeout(function() {
    target.classList.add("popAnimation");
  }, 10);
}

button.onclick = pop;
```

```css
.popAnimation {
  animation: popKeyframes 200ms linear both;
}

@keyframes popKeyframes {
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/prefixfree.js"></script>

<p id="textTarget">
  Here is the animation target.
</p>

<button type="button" id="button">Animate</button>
```

Comment: This question is to broad without seeing your code. I'm answering on my tablet now. Is it possible to make a [weave](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/)?

Comment: Sure, give me a few minutes to put something together.

Comment: Copy that. BTW: There's also [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/) of a [Weave](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor) is not possible.

Comment: [Here's an example.](https://jsfiddle.net/fkvqk0on/1/) Hope this helps!

Comment: You said "laggy and slow on my phone" and "Sometimes fails to animate if I swipe several times in a row". Could it be you may not be utilizing [`return false`](https://jsfiddle.net/fkvqk0on/2/) or maybe [`touchstart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchstart) and/or [`touchend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchend)? By Swipe what is it that's being swiped? (I assume a [gallery](http://fotorama.io/))

Comment: this link might help
https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tips-and-workarounds-performance-readme/

Comment: @TawfiqInjass Hmm... I didn't find much in that article that could apply here. The requestAnimationFrame function seems really interesting but the article only mentions adding callbacks to its events, not manipulating it. Thanks for the tips though!

Comment: @MichaelSchwartz I'm using the library [Hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io) to handle swiping. It helps me with a lot of the trickier things like multi-finger input. I'm using it for a certain command: swiping up is a "like". In this case, there's also a short vibration that happens, and this works instantly even when the animation fails to play. Because of that, I don't think that the swipe itself is an issue.

Comment: I haven't used [Hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/) sense 2014, a lot has changed with it in 2 years. [Have you considered removing the `both` property from your css animation?](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#d73d9dd35771bdd9f7989e251dd8b883) - `animation: popKeyframes 200ms linear;`

Comment: Removing `both` didn't seem to change it.

Answer (score 1):

With this CSS, added to your classes, you will trigger hardware acceleration, improving the performance of the animations

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
   -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
   -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
   -o-transform: translateZ(0);
   transform: translateZ(0);
```

Comment: I like your answer, simple and to the point! [Increase Your Site’s Performance with Hardware-Accelerated CSS](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css)

Comment: Thanks for this advice. I just tried it and while it did seem to make the animation smoother, it didn't change the lag from resetting the animation. I still see some failures to reset if I swipe quickly. Do you have any other ideas?